The variable is not bound error while trying to find an element using xpath (JYTHON SUT script) QF test
I have a simple SUT script (JYTHON). I'm trying to perform a basic operation wherein I'm finding a link that has the text "Welcome" and then clicking on it.I checked in the console and the element is present in is found if I use $x("//li//a[contains(text(),'Welcome')]")
enter image description here
Below is my code

# Define the XPath expression
    
com = rc.getComponent("genericDocument")
xpath_expression = "//li//a[contains(text(),'Welcome')]"
res = com.getByXPath(rc.lookup(xpath_expression))

# Perform actions on the found element
res.click()  # For example, click on the element

I went through the documentation and couldn't find anything on how to locate an element using xpath in SUT script.
P.S I'm new to QF test and any help would be really helpful
I trued using xpaths in the extra features as well to locate the element as such but with no luck
enter image description here

You don't need a Jython SUT Script in order to simply click a component. Just use the corresponding "Mouse click" node and then use
genericDocument@:xpath=${quoteitem://li//a[contains(text(),'Welcome')]}
as "QF-Test Component ID".
You can of course also fetch a reference to the component in a Jython SUT Script - see example 5.1, https://www.qfs.de/en/qf-test-manual/lc/manual-en-user_subitems.html#usec_xpath and in case your XPath is correct - but performing a click is not as simple as just a ".click()".
